# How to track a new born turtle in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

In the model that i have developed, turtles are born if a certain condition is met. When a new turtle is born, I want to track it i.e. if there are already 3 turtles alive and a 4th is born, i want to know which turtle was the newly-born.

Initially the system starts out with 2 turtles. So if a new turtle is born i first want to know that and then i want to track that turtle in terms of either `WHO` number or if there is a better way to do it.

To find if a new turtle is born, i initially thought of keeping count of the turtles in the previous tick and the current tick but since turtles can also die in my model the birth of a new party wont register if `turtle birth and death` happens simultaneously.

Comment: Does `watch` meet your needs?
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#watch

Comment: I am not sure `watch` helps since it only highlights a turtle. What i want to is know which turtle was born the last and a way to identify it. I can only think of `who` number to uniquely identify a turtle.

Comment: You mean you want to be able to identify the most recently born but still living turtle?  And when you do identify it, what do you want to do with that info?

Comment: Each turtle has its own set of measure which are updated by a separate routine. Once a turtle is born, the routine is called and `turtle-own` variables are updated. I want to store some of those variables for the most recently born turtle in a list. I know how to store the values but not sure how to identify the most recent born turtle though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this responds to your need:

```
to illustrate
  ca
  crt 2
  print [who] of turtles
  print-youngest
  ask turtles [hatch 1]
  print-youngest
  ask turtle who-of-youngest [die]
  print-youngest
end

to-report who-of-youngest
  report last sort [who] of turtles
end

to print-youngest
  print (word "turtle " who-of-youngest " is youngest.")
end
```